# ASP.NET MVC SelectList: How do I set class name and other attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

How can I set a select class and other attributes eg:events through the `SelectList` object?

If this cannot be done, what are the best practices in populating a select input (dropdownlist) ie should I just loop through the items and render the `<option>` tags

I guess events should be bound to the controls in jquery for instance, but I do need the class forto do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The htmlAttributes parameter should take an anonymous type initialised like this :

```
new {@class="some-css-class"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("elementname",yourSelectList,"defaultvalue",new{@class="yourclass"}) %>
```